# UIAlertController - Waiting for user response

Tags: swift, xcode

code 3 will be executed despite no response. How to wait for an answer?

```
         let alert = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: "Please answer: yes or not ?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                                
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                       
                // code 1...
                                                    
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { (action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                       
                // code 2...
            
            }))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

           // code 3...
```

Comment: Simply use the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `closures` for the `handler` parameter, and wait for the user's response:

```
func checkIfYesOrNo(handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: "Please answer: yes or not ?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: handler))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: handler))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Usage:

```
checkIfYesOrNo { action in
    if action.title == "Yes" {
        print("YES")
        // code 3...
    } else {
        print("NO")
        // code 3...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to get output of your alert with completion handler like this.. **`Easy to use`**

```
func showAlert(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: "Please answer: yes or not ?", preferredStyle: .alert)
          

       // add the actions (buttons)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: {action in 
          
         // code 1...

          completion(true)

        }))

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: { action in

         // code 2...

         completion(false)

       }))
    
     present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**How to use**

```
showAlert { isSuccess in

  isSuccess ? print("true") : print("false")

 // isSuccess is bool having true or false accordingly 

   // code 3... here

}
```